# Why xgboost.get_booster().get_score() doesn't return any value for one of the variables?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost, feature-selection, feature-engineering

A few questions about feature importance in xgboost in python:

- I'm trying to print the feature importance using xgboost.get_booster().get_score(). However, the function sometimes doesn't return anything for some variables. Does that mean the score for those variables is 0?
- Why the results of xgboost.get_booster().get_score() looks so different from xgboost.feature_importance_ ?
- About the importance_type in get_score(); what would be a a reasonable option for a multi-class classification task? It seems the default in python is "weight", but according to [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/be-careful-when-interpreting-your-features-importance-in-xgboost-6e16132588e7) importance_type = 'gain' makes more sense (I agree). However, when I use importance_type = 'gain' the results don't make as much sense as the default value for importance_type.

Thank you!